# How can I search for "Only happens on my machine" questions? ( is there a tag)

Tags: support, search

I spent all day on a problem that was only happening on my machine.
It turned out that I needed to reset the visual studio debugger to default settings.
Now I want to look for similar questions. What tag should I be using?

Comment: There is no such tag, because that would be a meta-tag.

Comment: is there such a thing as a meta-tag?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @Doorknob I think you may be confusing terms; this one isn't a meta  tag.

Comment: @Emrak Yes it is. Can it stand on its own? No. So, it's a meta tag.

Comment: the tag "to be" for such cases is "closed as too localized" :)

Comment: @Doorknob A meta tag is one which does not describe the contents of the post.

Comment: @Emrakul A meta-tag is one which does not largely describe the subject matter or topic of the post and **will not stand on its own**. Another way to look at it is whether there would be any experts for the tag in question. Who would be an expert on [tag:only-happens-on-my-machine]?

Comment: @Emrak And does this tag describe the contents of the post? (hint: no)

Comment: @Asheesh Ah, right. That makes sense. But wait - a tag can be descriptive and have no specific experts. I had this debate with Yannis over a programming challenge tag, but I don't remember what we decided...

Comment: @Door I would say that it _would_ describe the contents of the post, in that it only occurs on one computer.

Comment: @Emrak By that logic [subjective] does too, because it tells you that the post's contents are subjective. Or [beginner] does too, because it tells you that the post has beginner knowledge in it.

Comment: @Door I agree that this tag would be ineffective, but I think that's not a linear comparison. This tag is far more descriptive than [subjective] or [beginner].

Comment: @Emrak Okay, I agree with that, but this is getting very off topic :P let's stop talking about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a tag?

No. As stated in the comments, it would be a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

> What tag should I be using?

Look under the topic tags [visual-studio-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-*) and use advanced search features.

Answer (score 2):

That tag does not exist. With the previous close reason set, we would call that "too localized" - in other words, the question is so specific to you and the circumstances in which your specific computer is configured that the answer will likely not help anyone in the future.

Effectively, it would indicate that the problem is yours only - it is not reproducible anywhere but in one location. The solution, in this case, is to restart your IDE - advice which typically is the first step of debugging.

The second problem is that there isn't a very good English phrase to capture the idea of "only occurs on one device."  Or, at least, I can't think of one off the top of my head, and I haven't seen one around.

Comment: Actually, there was one tag that captures that : [tag:works-on-my-machine].

Comment: @Asheesh I want my WOMMy.

Comment: Not anymore there isn't...

Comment: Besides, I think "works-on-my-machine" describes a slightly different scenario than "only-happens-on-my-machine" (which is usually synonymous with "does-not-work-on-my-machine").